# PyQt5 + VTK - wglMakeCurrent failed error

Tags: pyqt5, vtk, qvtkwidget

Minimum working example:

```
from sys import exit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QFrame
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import vtkmodules.all as vtk
from vtkmodules.util import numpy_support
import numpy as np

vtk_out = vtk.vtkOutputWindow()
vtk_out.SetDisplayMode(0)

def generate_qtvtk_sphere(parent):
    frame = QFrame(parent)
    vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(frame)

    ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(ren)
    iren = vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

    # Create source
    source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
    source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
    source.SetRadius(5.0)

    # Create a mapper
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

    # Create an actor
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    ren.AddActor(actor)

    ren.ResetCamera()

    iren.Initialize()
    iren.Start()

    return vtkWidget

def generate_qtvtk_imagedata(parent):
    frame = QFrame(parent)
    vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(frame)

    random_array = np.random.random([10, 600, 800])
    vtk_image_data = vtk.vtkImageData()

    image_array = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(random_array.ravel(), deep=True, array_type=vtk.VTK_TYPE_UINT16)
    vtk_image_data.GetPointData().SetScalars(image_array)
    vtk_image_data.Modified()

    reslice = vtk.vtkImageReslice()
    reslice.SetInputData(vtk_image_data)    
    reslice.SetOutputDimensionality(2)
    
    ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(ren)
    iren = vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

    # Create an actor
    actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
    actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(reslice.GetOutputPort())
    ren.SetBackground(50, 50, 50)

    ren.AddActor(actor)

    ren.ResetCamera()

    interactorStyle = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleImage()
    vtkWidget.SetInteractorStyle(interactorStyle)
    vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().SetInteractor(vtkWidget)
    vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().Render()


    iren.Initialize()
    iren.Start()

    return vtkWidget


app = QApplication([])
main_window = QMainWindow()

main_widget = QWidget()
main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

qtvtk_widget_sphere = generate_qtvtk_sphere(main_widget)
qtvtk_widget_image = generate_qtvtk_imagedata(main_widget)

main_layout.addWidget(qtvtk_widget_image)
main_layout.addWidget(qtvtk_widget_sphere)

main_window.setCentralWidget(main_widget)


main_window.show()
app.exec()
```

The output of this code should be a pyqt window with a sphere on one side and a randomly-generated black square on the other. The square is representative of the datasets that I normally deal with.

The relevant packages in my conda env are:

- vtk 9.1.0
- pyqt5 5.15.7
- python 3.7.13 (cant upgrade due to dependency on another package)

The full error I get looks like this:

[image]

---

Original post follows:

In my application, I have two `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor`, on two different QWidgets, that are mostly independent from each other - there's a function outside the interactors that updates the contents of both interactors at the same thing, but that's it.

Whenever the application displays both interactors, I get the following error when the app closes:

```
2022-08-23 13:51:07.522 (  10.079s) [                ]vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWin:267    ERR| vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (00000194B174E4C0): wglMakeCurrent failed in MakeCurrent(), error: ࣐Ɣ
```

The error part in the end looks like this on the debugger

[image]

and there's usually a lot of these errors that pop up.

My other application (same idea, qt, same interactor, same set-up) has these lines in the beginning of the code

```
vtk_out = vtkOutputWindow()
vtk_out.SetDisplayMode(0)
```

which suppresses the errors for that one.

But in my other progra,, I need to use a QWorker/QThread in order to update the interactor, and outputting the error to console doesn't work anymore (it creates a new window with the same error, and then freezes everything).

I just want to know what the heck these errors are and how to get rid of them.

Also, the code I'm using the setup the interactor is as follows:

In the widget:

```
        self._frame = QGroupBox()
        self.interactor = ViewerPanelVTK(self._frame)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.interactor)
```

where

```
class ViewerPanelVTK(QVTKRenderWindowInteractor):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.panel_actor = vtkImageActor()
        self.panel_renderer = vtkRenderer()
        self.window = self.GetRenderWindow()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found the answer myself eventually in the VTK discourse forum.](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/wglmakecurrent-failed-in-makecurrent-after-closed-a-window-with-two-vtk-widget/5899/2)

Apparently the widget needs to be closed so that this error won't show.

The sample code from the original answer follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import vtk

class vtkWin(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()
        layout.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)
        render = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(render)

        cone_a=vtk.vtkConeSource()
        coneMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        coneMapper.SetInputConnection(cone_a.GetOutputPort())
        coneActor = vtk.vtkActor()
        coneActor.SetMapper(coneMapper)
        render.AddActor(coneActor)
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().Render()

    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        super().closeEvent(QCloseEvent)
        self.vtkWidget.Finalize()     ############################ important

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.w1 = vtkWin()
        self.w2 = vtkWin()
        layout.addWidget(self.w1)
        layout.addWidget(self.w2)

    def closeEvent(self, QCloseEvent):
        super().closeEvent(QCloseEvent)
        self.w1.close()
        self.w2.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```